# Remove ghost entries from LXDE start menu

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, menulibre

There is an invalid entry left by Atom editor (authors failed to provide an unistaller). Entries are not removable using `menulibre` - it is not listing them, but ghost entries remain in menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for fitting .desktop files and removing them may help.

In that case removal of /usr/local/share/applications/Atom.desktop fixed problem.

Solution found on http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?p=48112&sid=51e194b86f5901892036da51a76a55db#p48112